# Differentiability of Absolute Value Function

Tags: derivatives, continuity, absolute-value

I know it isn't differentiable at $0$ as the limit of $\frac{|x|}{x}$ does not exist as $x$ approaches $0$.

I want to check though for all other $x$ values as the derivative should be $1$ for positive values and $-1$ for negative values.

Taking the limit as $x \to a$ of  $\frac{|x|-|a|}{x-a}$. Now do I consider the two cases:

1. $|x|-|a| > 0$, then we get $1$, if $a$ is positive.
2. $|x|-|a| < 0$, then we get $-1$, if $a$ is negative.

I'm not sure how to show that the derivative is $1$ for positive $x$ values and $-1$ for negative $x$ values.

Comment: Sorry also, I didn't notice your mistake in your 1. and 2.: the two cases are just $a>0$ and $a<0$. The sign of $|x|-|a|$ is irrelevant. When you look for the limit, you just have to replace $|x|-|a|$ by $x-a$ when $a>0$ (since $x$ close to $a$ hence also $>0$) and similarly by $(-x)-(-a)$ when $a<0.$

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me since the absolute values are around two separate variables. If it were $|x-a|$, then that would make sense to me.

Comment: On the contrary, my replacements wouldn't make sense for $|x-a|$ since we don't know the sign of $x-a.$ But in each case ($a>0$ and $a<0$) they make sense for $|x|$ and $|a|$ since we know the (common) sign of $a$ and $x.$

Comment: Okay, I understand your point. Can I see a full proof if you have time, because I'm uncertain about my explanation for the final steps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of absolute value $x\mapsto |x|:=\begin{cases}x,\quad x>0\\0,\quad x=0\\-x,\quad x<0,\end{cases}$ then applying the definition to derivative,$$\frac{|x|-|a|}{x-a}=\begin{cases}\frac{x-a}{x-a},\quad a>0,x>0 ,\\\frac{-(x-a)}{x-a},\quad a<0,x<0\end{cases}$$
Hence
$$|~|'(a)=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{|x|-|a|}{x-a}=\begin{cases}1,\quad a>0,\\-1,\quad a<0.\end{cases}$$
A simpler method is:

- on $(0,+\infty),$ the function $|~|$ coincides with the function $f:x\mapsto x$, hence $|~|'=f'=1.$
- on $(-\infty,0),$ the function $|~|$ coincides with the function $g:x\mapsto-x$, hence $|~|'=g'=-1.$